# AJAX Post Request for application with Reverse Proxy not working

Tags: ajax, iis-7.5, http-post, reverse-proxy

We have an two applications setup on same server.  IIS 7.5,Windows 2008 R2.

Application 1 : Port 80/443
Application 2 (app2) : Port 444

We've used ARR Module with reverse Proxy to route all requests with *testsite.com/app2/* to port 444 using article.

[here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

All of the things are working fine, however when we try to do a AJAX POST request, it gives 502 Error, Probable due to Same Origin Code Policy violation since response is coming form different port number.

AJAX request works **fine** when we access website using port number like below:
*testsite:444/app2/*

We can't Use JSON P since we need to do HTTP Post, also I would want to avoid Using CORS, need some solution from server side.

Regards,
Tarun Panwar

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The issue was that there was one module entry which was causing some issues, removed that module and everything was working fine.

Regrads,
Tarun

Comment: can you please share the more detailed answer I am having same problem.